# Change scroll lines when use mouse wheels?

Tags: x11, mouse, xfce

Is there a way to control how many lines will scroll, when you use the mouse wheels? It seems to be 5 lines by default, anyway to change this value?

I didn't find it in xfce4-settings-manager

Answer (score 3):

Every *tick* of the wheel actually generates a `ButtonPress` and `ButtonRelease` (of mouse button 4 (Up) and 5 (Down)). Basically, using the wheel is like clicking a virtual up or down button repeatedly. How those events are used to scroll lines or something else is down to the application.

For example, with firefox, type `about:config` in the location bar and change the setting for `mousewheel.withnokey.numlines` and disable `mousewheel.withnokey.sysnumlines`

What application would you like to modify?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [imwheel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/imwheel/), as there is [no option](http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg/2011-December/053927.html) to set this in X config currently.