# Increase the number of lines scrolled by a mouse wheel tick, everywhere

Tags: x11, mouse, scrolling

When I use the mouse wheel, I want to be able to configure it to scroll by multiple lines at a time, e.g. each tick would scroll 5 lines. In [Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-mouse-settings#1TC=windows-7) you can increase or decrease the number of lines scrolled with the mouse wheel. As far as I know this is also possible in OSX. This is a OS setting that changes it for each application. I want the same thing under Linux.

In Chrome, I increase the number of lines scroller per wheel tick with an add-on, but I do not want to find a add-on for each application I use. I want a global solution.

I've tried imwheel but it's a hack that removes other functionality. For example, with Sublime, the imwheel solution changes the working of the scroll wheel completely.

Why has this not been a default feature in Linux? I've been looking for this for over 10 years.

Comment: Could you expand on your explanation of the problem? I have no idea what “mouse wheel scrolling being very low” means, or how to parse “Mouse scroll lines mouse wheel”. I get that you're trying to do something about/with the wheel on your mouse, but what? Is there an application where it doesn't react? Is it doing the wrong thing?

Comment: Sorry, thought it was clear. It is purely lines scrolled per mouse wheel tick. In chrome I increase it with an addon, but I do not want to find a addon for each application I use. It is a problem I and many other have for quite long time, with each mouse I have used over the last 10 years.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand correctly. Do you want to scroll multiple lines per mouse wheel tick? That would be a per-application setting — the application decides what it does when it receives a wheel tick, and many applications in my experience (both on Linux and on Windows) scroll one line per tick.

Comment: So in windows you can increase or decrease the number of lines scrolled with the mouse wheel. [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-mouse-settings#1TC=windows-7) see mousewheel. As far as I know this is also possible in OSX. This is a OS setting that changes it for each application. However this is not possible in any Linux distribution I have found so far. 
Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks, got it. I voted to reopen. What desktop environment do you use? There's no global setting, but there might be one at least for a specific widget library.

Comment: Your question is basically a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49061/change-scroll-lines-when-use-mouse-wheels (which was asking about XFCE, but only got generic “no” answers).

Comment: However http://askubuntu.com/questions/22589/how-to-change-my-mouse-wheel-scroll-rate suggests that a global setting now exists — I don't know how it works though.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. But I do not think it is a real duplicate, since my main question is to discover the reason why this is not in Linux. I am just wondering why this might be something that is so hard to program. I find it strange that other Unix based operating systems (OSX) are able to have this. Considering the fix, that is about mousewheel acceleration, so the faster you turn the more lines you go. Still no mouse wheel tick number of lines scrolled. Ah well I might just have to give up hope.